# Win2k8 + SQL Server 2008 x64 - AMD Quad Opteron vs Intel Quad Xeon - Real Benchmarks

Tags: sql-server-2008, hardware, intel, amd-processor

We're getting new servers. Trying to figure out the AMD vs Intel holy war. Is there anywhere to find unbiased performance comparisons of these two processor families? Should I quit worrying about this and file it into the "it doesn't matter" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My #1 benchmark site is [anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com). I find their reviews quite complete.

Now, depending on your server usage, the extra n% that an Opteron or Xeon may give you may or may not be of matter to you. Always take into account the usage that you are going to give to your servers when comparing CPUs and benchmarks.